# styled-components - IE11 support - Invalid characters

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` in my React app. I'm using it this way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled  from 'styled-components';
 
const CheckboxContainer = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right:5px;
`
```

This is works fine in all modern browsers. As I saw on caniuse.com, the apostrophe-sign (`) is not supported in IE11.

It throws an error, when I open the app in IE11:

[image]

which means

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
```

I know that there are possibilities to add `polyfills` in JS, but is there an option to add this functionality, too? I'm wondering that I did not find any similar question, so maybe there is a simple solution, which I do not see at the moment.

Comment: are you transpiling your code with babel?

Comment: Sorry, I actually don't know this. I've created the app with `create-react-app` and i'm using the standard functions `npm start` or `npm run build`. How can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add polyfills for react to work on IE. Add this libraries to the beggining of index.js file and downgrade to `react-scripts` version `3.2.0`.

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'raf/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[JavaScript Environment Requirements](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html)

[react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill)

[Syntax error - IE11 - Polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6924)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does not solve the issue. The error message still appears

Comment: did you add the polyfills at the top, before anything else?

Comment: No, the same as you posted. Directly on the top.

Comment: oh I forgot you need to also use ```"react-scripts": "3.2.0```

Comment: So you mean this exact version of `react-scripts`? I'm currently using `"react-scripts": "3.4.1",`

Comment: yes the polyfills doesn't work with other versions of react scripts

Comment: I did not get it to work on `npm start`, but with `npm run build` it works also in IE11 now. I've added `import 'core-js'; import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` to `index.js` and `ie-11` in `package.json` in section `browserlist`. Many thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution by Junius L. worked for me.

Solution steps:

1. `npm install react-app-polyfill`
2. Add the libraries in index.js file
   Note: It worked without downgrading the "react-scripts". 
   [image: snapshot of package.json]
3. Update the browserlist in package.json

   ```
    
   "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ],
       "development": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ]
     }
   ```

Comment: I did not get it to work on `npm start`, but with `npm run build` it works also in IE11 now. I've added `import 'core-js'; import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` to `index.js` and `ie-11` in `package.json` in section `browserlist`. Many thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a React sample using `"react-scripts": "3.4.1"`, after adding the [`react-app-polyfill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) polyfill for IE browser and install the Styled Components, I could use the Styled Components to add CSS style.

Details steps as below:

1. Create a new React Application using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).
2. Add [Polyfill for IE browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill).

   Install the package: `install the package`

   Add the following code in the src/index.js

   ```
   import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
   import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
   import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
   ```

   Change the browserslist in package.json

   ```
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version",
         "ie 11"
       ]
     }
   ```
3. Install Styled Components using NPM, with the command below:

   ```
    npm install styled-components
   ```
4. Using the Styled Components

   Code in the app.js:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';
   import styled from 'styled-components';

   const Button = styled.button`
     cursor: pointer;
     background: transparent;
     font-size: 16px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: palevioletred;
     border: 2px solid palevioletred;
     margin: 0 1em;
     padding: 0.25em 1em;
     transition: 0.5s all ease-out;

     &:hover {
       background-color: palevioletred;
       color: white;
     }
   `;

   function App() {
     return (
       <div className="App"> 
         <div>
         <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
         <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
         <Button>I am a Button</Button>
       </div>
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```

   and the package.json page as below

   ```
   {
     "name": "reactstylecomponent",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
       "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
       "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
       "react": "^16.13.1",
       "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
       "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
       "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
       "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
       "webpack": "4.42.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app"
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version",
         "ie 11"
       ]
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "webpack": "^4.42.0"
     }
   }
   ```
5. After running the website in IE 11 browser, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's really mad. All of the solutions doesn't work in my case. The error is still the same.

Comment: Try to clear the IE browser data (cache, cookie and so on) and the cache folder under the application node_modules folder. Then, retest the website  in IE browser.

Comment: It looks like the error is a different one, but it shows the error on the line above in the image.

Comment: I did not get it to work on `npm start`, but with `npm run build` it works also in IE11 now. I've added `import 'core-js'; import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` to `index.js` and `ie-11` in `package.json` in section `browserlist`. Many thanks all for your help.